# Angular : Is it possible to load a custom css file into component and work on children component as well

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have CSS file, and I want to import it into the component.   it should works on all subcomponent as well.

For example,

I have two module, `website` and `admin`. Now, What I want is to `import` my custom CSS into `website` component template. It should apply to all children component of `website` component, not `admin` module components.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. you need to create on style file into module and need to import in all component's css file. those class declare in this style file which is used global into module.

Comment: Ok, so I have 100 components, I need to import in all component, is there any better way? because I am loading one file 100 times.

Comment: i have one question. you have used same class name for both module?

Comment: I have used the bootstrap class, and I want to overwrite some of the class in another module. because each module has a different template.

Comment: i think you need to import into all component.and it's not  effect on performance

Answer (score 0):

For the moment you can preface your selectors with `::ng-deep` to force child components to take on those styles.

example:

`::ng-deep h1 {
   color: red;
}`

will make all h1 elements under the current component red

This is deprecated though as browsers are removing support for this functionality.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: The same thing I want for the file.